# Форма не работает

Tags: php, форма

Скажите почему не работает форма, я отправляю данные, но ввел ли я одинаковые пароли или нет, сообщение об ошибке не выскакивает! Может что не так написал?

```
<?php header('content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');?>
<form action="reg.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" required> <br/>
    <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин" required> <br/>
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Пароль" required> <br/>
    <input type="password" name="confirm_pass" placeholder="Подтверждение пароля" required> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Регистрация">
</form>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $confirm_pass = $_POST['confirm_pass'];
    if($pass == $confirm_pass){
        $pass = md5($pass);
    } else {
        die("Пароли не совпадают!");
    };
};
?>
```

Comment: @sew810i9, кода не так много- нет нужды выкладывать в другое место. Тем более в файлы.мэйл.ру.  
Есть кстати чудесный http://ideone.com

Comment: извините, но я сначала сам код пытался вставить но чет при нажатии "Отправить" меня кидало на пустую страницу, думал из-за кода, вот и выложил в обменник

Answer (score 4):

Вы проверяете

```
$_POST["submit"]
```

но поля ввода с таким именем у Вас нет. До проверки равенства паролей дело даже не доходит. Надо делать хотя бы так:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Регистрация">
```

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, никакого `$_POST['submit']` не будет, у вашей кнопки не указано `name="submit"`.
Во-вторых, вы бы написали как файл называется, может он у вас не `reg.php`.

Comment: спасибо, я порой делаю просто нелепые ошибки то ли из-за невнимательности то ли надо больше практиковаться

Comment: @sew810i9, нестрашно